# Select rows based on calculation result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to select the 3 fastest moving events in my database. I get the fastest moving by subtracting (game_start - game_current) and take the absolute value of that.

Here is what I am trying to do. Obviously not correct syntax but just to give you idea of what I am trying to do.

```
@fast_moving = Event.where("(ABS(game_start - game_current)) > ?", 3)[0..2]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `.limit(3)` instead of `[0..2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where almost there!

```
Event.where("(ABS(game_start) - ABS(game_current)) > ?", 3).limit(3)
```

The `.limit(3)` will limit the results to only 3 results, at the db-level.

You could make a scope of it:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :moving_fast, lambda { |duration| 
                        where("(ABS(game_start) - ABS(game_current)) > ?", duration || 3) }
```

And use it like this:

```
@fast_events = Event.moving_fast.limit(3)
# or
@fast_events = Event.moving_fast(5)
```

(You can pass a `duration` argument to the scope)

Comment: I need the absolute value of game_start - game_current. Each can be positive or negative number so need absolute value. How do I get that in there?

Comment: I need to know what DB adapter you are using. PostGreSQL ? MySQL ? Something else?

Comment: sqlite3 local and PG on Heroku deployment

Comment: Hmm I recommend you to use the same DB system in production and development, it will prevent from raising errors about not compatible queries. Well What I just updated should work on PG, I don't know about SQLite3 (for `ABS()`)

Comment: Actually, it should work on SQLite too: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html (first method `abs(x)`)